# It is correct to ask for permission in the view or it should be the model in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

People, I've readed a tons of posts regarding this matter and I couldn't see the light yet on here.

It's pretty easy to ask for a permission to execute/do or show something in the view as in the controller, but is more complex to do it in the model, at least is what happened to me.
in the controller, because you can access easily to the session object: HttpContext.Current.Session["UserPermissions"] and from the view I could have a sessionmanager and accesing like this: SessionManager.IsAllowed(Permission.SuperUser) and that is also constructed in the controller. But how can we do it easly in the Model and the business layer that connect to the database?

This is my example-

When I need to get some information from database and based in the user permission, I would like to do not fill an object with data that I know the user does not has access.

It's easy to parse the object in the view and showing just the items the user is allow to see, but is not even better filtrate this items before bring them to the view?

Can someone show me an example where I implement a permission class to use it cross all my models?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick example abut what I have.

A check in the view: 
if (SessionManager.IsAllowed(Permission.DoChargebackAction))

A method in the controller:
        public static bool IsAllowed(Permission permission)
        {
            return GetUserPermissions().Contains(permission);
        }

        public static IList<Permission> GetUserPermissions()
        {
            if (SessionManager.IsNullUserPermissionSession())
                return new List<Permission>();

            return (IList<Permission>)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserPermissions"];
        }

Comment: Your model should not "reach out" to get any data.  If it has dependencies on things like permissions from a session, etc., that data should be passed *into* the model.

Answer (score 0):

I typically have a CurrentUser class that resides alongside in the model, where I keep track of all important user attributes, such as permissions, User ID, name, e-mail address, et cetera.  Keeping the class inside the model allows easy access for controllers, which is where a large portion of permission checks might occur, depending on your application.  This would also allow the CurrentUser model to be passed to the view as a View Model.

I restrict items in the view based on what roles the user currently has in their CurrentUser class and only pass the CurrentUser object to the view when necessary.  The CurrentUser class is instantiated on the start of the application and can be updated as much or as little as needed.  A current application I'm working on requires that the user's roles be updated fairly frequently.

Checking user permissions in the controller and model can be done easily if the roles are kept inside the CurrentUser object.  Implementing a method such as (using MVC Simple Membership Provider):

```
bool IsUserInRole(string roleName) {
    if (currentUser != null)
        {
            return currentUser.Roles.Contains(roleName);
        }
}
```

gives you the ability to check against the current roles, regardless of what portion of the MVC you are currently in.

I would recommend against passing the CurrentUser to the Data Abstraction Layer (the layer that sits on top of the database), and instead implement methods in a way that either the access requirement can be passed in as a parameter or implement separate methods for each role that you might be using.